# How to use CAS SSO with JHipster

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, single-sign-on, jhipster

I genereted an application using JHipster and I would like to use my instance of jasig CAS as SSO with my application instead of default form login that comes with the app. Ultimately I would like to use custom CAS parameters to assign authorities.

I followed this [example](https://github.com/jgribonvald/demo-spring-cas-angular). Now I have the app generated with JHipster which I successfully connected to my CAS. When I type `localhost:8080/app/login` it redirects me to my CAS instance, authenticates me and redirects back to JHipster app but JHipster doesn't let me browse the secured part of my the app and still requires authentication. Below is my `SecurityConfiguration.java`. Can somone provide any insight as to how proceed from here?

```
package com.my.company.application.config;

import org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter;
import org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties;
import org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAssertionAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.AuthenticationUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import pl.edu.uw.dsk.konferator.security.*;
import pl.edu.uw.dsk.konferator.web.filter.CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String CAS_URL_LOGIN = "cas.url.login";
    private static final String CAS_URL_LOGOUT = "cas.url.logout";
    private static final String CAS_URL_PREFIX = "cas.url.prefix";
    private static final String CAS_SERVICE_URL = "app.service.security";
    private static final String CAS_CALLBACK = "/auth/cas";

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Inject
    private AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler;

    /*@Inject
    private AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler;*/

    @Inject
    private AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Inject
    private AuthenticationUserDetailsService<CasAssertionAuthenticationToken> userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServiceProperties serviceProperties() {
        ServiceProperties sp = new ServiceProperties();
        sp.setService(env.getRequiredProperty(CAS_SERVICE_URL));
        sp.setSendRenew(false);
        return sp;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        authenticationSuccessHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
        authenticationSuccessHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("spring-security-redirect");
        return authenticationSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public RememberCasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() {
        RememberCasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider = new RememberCasAuthenticationProvider();
        casAuthenticationProvider.setAuthenticationUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        casAuthenticationProvider.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
        casAuthenticationProvider.setTicketValidator(cas20ServiceTicketValidator());
        casAuthenticationProvider.setKey("CAS_AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER");
        return casAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionStrategy() {
        SessionFixationProtectionStrategy sessionStrategy = new SessionFixationProtectionStrategy();
        sessionStrategy.setMigrateSessionAttributes(false);
        //sessionStrategy.setRetainedAttributes(Arrays.asList("CALLBACKURL"));
        return sessionStrategy;
    }

/*
    @Bean
    public Saml11TicketValidator casSamlServiceTicketValidator() {
        return new Saml11TicketValidator(env.getRequiredProperty(CAS_URL_PREFIX));
    }
*/

    @Bean
    public Cas20ServiceTicketValidator cas20ServiceTicketValidator() {
        return new Cas20ServiceTicketValidator(env.getRequiredProperty(CAS_URL_PREFIX));
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter = new CasAuthenticationFilter();
        casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationDetailsSource(new RememberWebAuthenticationDetailsSource());
        casAuthenticationFilter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionStrategy());
        casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler);
        casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler());
        casAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl(CAS_CALLBACK);
        // casAuthenticationFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new
        // AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "GET"));
        return casAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public RememberCasAuthenticationEntryPoint casAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        RememberCasAuthenticationEntryPoint casAuthenticationEntryPoint = new RememberCasAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        casAuthenticationEntryPoint.setLoginUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(CAS_URL_LOGIN));
        casAuthenticationEntryPoint.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
        //move to /app/login due to cachebuster instead of api/authenticate
        casAuthenticationEntryPoint.setPathLogin("/app/login");
        return casAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter() {
        SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter = new SingleSignOutFilter();
        singleSignOutFilter.setCasServerUrlPrefix(env.getRequiredProperty(CAS_URL_PREFIX));
        return singleSignOutFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LogoutFilter requestCasGlobalLogoutFilter() {
        LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter(env.getRequiredProperty(CAS_URL_LOGOUT) + "?service="
            + env.getRequiredProperty(CAS_SERVICE_URL), new SecurityContextLogoutHandler());
        // logoutFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/logout");
        // logoutFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/j_spring_cas_security_logout");
        logoutFilter.setLogoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/logout", "POST"));
        return logoutFilter;
    }

    @Inject
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(casAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/scripts/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/bower_components/**")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/assets/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
            .antMatchers("/test/**")
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(casAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(singleSignOutFilter(), CasAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(requestCasGlobalLogoutFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(casAuthenticationEntryPoint())
//        .and()
//            .rememberMe()
//            .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
//            .key(env.getProperty("jhipster.security.rememberme.key"))
//        .and()
//            .formLogin()
//            .loginProcessingUrl("/api/authentication")
//            .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
//            .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
//            .usernameParameter("j_username")
//            .passwordParameter("j_password")
//            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/app/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset_password/init").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset_password/finish").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/logs/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/api/audits/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/metrics/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/health/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/trace/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/dump/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/shutdown/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/beans/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/configprops/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/info/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/autoconfig/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/env/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/trace/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/mappings/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/liquibase/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/configuration/security").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/configuration/ui").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/protected/**").authenticated();
    }

    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
    private static class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
        public GlobalSecurityConfiguration() {
            super();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I am having the same problem. Once am authenticated with cas and get back to jhipster app, it still thinks that i need to login.

Comment: @MaverickRiz No. Im still tackling this issue. I'm thinking of intercepting the CAS token I get in return and using that to authenticate user in database. Once I'm done I'll probably update this Q with my answer.

Comment: I was able to solve this by getting UserDetails from the security context. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jhipste doesn't know that you are authenticated, thats the reason it does not let you browse secure pages. If you look closely in your principal.service.js and auth.service.js, they are calling the api/account rest service in AccountResource, and based on this angular determins if you are authenticated or not. So that means we need to return an User from this rest service.

Once you logged in with cas the current user info can be obtained from the AccounResource Rest service.  Below is my AccountResource

```
/**
 * GET  /account -> get the current user.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/account",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> getAccount() {
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (GrantedAuthority authority : userDetails.getGrantedAuthorities()) {
        roles.add(authority.getAuthorigy());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(
        new UserDTO(
            user.getLogin(),
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            roles),
        HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

As you can see above, i am getting authentication(casauthentication) token from security context. I have refactored my AccountResource to remove all the reference to user repository as i am no longer using the database to store user info. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: This is pretty old question but as my understanding grew I now know that you need to wire some REST endpoint to your routing that will tell you whether you are authentiated or not. It can't be done without call to backend since it's the backend that knows that you are indeed authenticated. I'm glad to mark this answer as correct. :)